# Google placeautocomplete load result after first letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I need help with my googleplaceautocomplete script. I spent almost 58 hours on it but still don't have any clue how to get the solution.

If I type 20 street and click on picklist result it returns full address:
20 street, Los angeles, California, United State. While I want to display 20 street only. Somehow I managed to get the street address only.

But issue is when I click on any pick list result (dropdown results) it returns the complete address in textbox first then my script returns my address there. I tried to stop the complete address populating in textbox when user click dropdown results but I failed to find solution.

You can check my code here:  http://pastebin.com/h9qkhLQw

You can check my live example here:  http://bhargavshastri.com/gmap-streetaddress/dipu/2.html

I have been trying this for 1 week. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This certainly isn't the most elegant solution but I was struggling to find a way of doing it via the API exposed...

I used a second input field (initially hidden behind the autocomplete input field) which I then bring to the front upon selection of a place from the autocomplete list (so it hides the real autocomplete). This prevents the user seeing the complete address being populated in the textbox. See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gc9y33op/6/) for a demo.

HTML:

```
<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text" onchange="hideAutocomplete()" />
  <!-- Hidden field -->
  <input id="autocompleteDummy" type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#autocomplete,
#autocompleteDummy {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 99%;
}

#autocompleteDummy {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Javascript:

```
/*
 * Function called when the value in the autocomplete textbox changes so it hides the real autocomplete and displays the 'fake' one
 */
function hideAutocomplete() {
   // Populate the fake autocomplete with the text typed by the user - this prevents a blank box appearing
   document.getElementById('autocompleteDummy').value = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
   // Display the fake autocomplete
   document.getElementById('autocompleteDummy').style.zIndex = 1;
   // Hide the real autcomplete
   document.getElementById('autocomplete').style.zIndex = -1;
}
```

You will also need to modify your `initAutocomplete()` function to display the real autocomplete after populating the address fields. To do this, add the following lines right before the end of the method and after your for loop:

```
 // Display the real autocomplete and hide the fake one
 document.getElementById('autocomplete').style.zIndex = 1;
 document.getElementById('autocompleteDummy').style.zIndex = -1;
```

I'd be interested to see if anyone could come up with a better solution as this still feels a bit 'hacky' to me.